# Get the max value for each key in a Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

What is the best way to return the max row (value) associated with each unique key in a spark RDD?

I'm using python and I've tried Math max, mapping and reducing by keys and aggregates. Is there an efficient way to do this? Possibly an UDF?

I have in RDD format:

```
[(v, 3),
 (v, 1),
 (v, 1),
 (w, 7),
 (w, 1),
 (x, 3),
 (y, 1),
 (y, 1),
 (y, 2),
 (y, 3)]
```

And I need to return:

```
[(v, 3),
 (w, 7),
 (x, 3),
 (y, 3)]
```

Ties can return the first value or random.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually you have a PairRDD. One of the best ways to do it is with reduceByKey:

(Scala)

```scala
val grouped = rdd.reduceByKey(math.max(_, _))
```

(Python)

```py
grouped = rdd.reduceByKey(max)
```

(Java 7)

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> grouped = new JavaPairRDD(rdd).reduceByKey(
    new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
            return Math.max(v1, v2);
    }
});
```

(Java 8)

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> grouped = new JavaPairRDD(rdd).reduceByKey(
    (v1, v2) -> Math.max(v1, v2)
);
```

API doc for reduceByKey:

- [Scala](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions)
- [Python](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey)
- [Java](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html)

Comment: can you give a way to do this in Java as well? I am using java and looking for exactly the same thing

Comment: @tsar2512 With Java 8, this might work: `new JavaPairRDD(rdd).reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> Math.max(v1, v2));`

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately, I am using Java 7 - it does not allow lambda functions. One typically has to write anonymous functions. Could you let me know what would be the solution in Java 7? I suspext a simple comparator function should work!

Comment: Additionally. What we are getting is the max of values which belong to each key. Is that correct?

Comment: @tsar2512, yes, the resulting RDD will contain a single entry for each key, containing a pair (key, maxValue). I updated the answer with versions for Java 7 and Java 8, but I haven't tested them, so please let me know if it works.

Comment: @DanieldePaula what if the initial RDD has tuples e.g. `[(v,(125,12)), (v, (130,15)), (w,(200,30)), (w,(250,40))]` instead of just a value and you need to find the result with the max value of the first element such as `[(v, (130,15)),(w,(250,40))]`