# How do I find the minimum date for each unique key in an RDD with PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a list of tuples of the format, [(ID, Date), (ID, Date)...], with dates in datetime format.  As an example of the RDD I'm working with:

```
[('1', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('2', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('3', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('4', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('5', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('1', datetime.date(2011, 1, 01)),
 ('2', datetime.date(2013, 1, 01)),
 ('3', datetime.date(2015, 1, 01)),
 ('4', datetime.date(2010, 1, 01)),
 ('5', datetime.date(2018, 1, 01))]
```

I need to gather the IDs and the minimum date associated with each ID.  Presumably, this is a `reduceByKey` action, but I've not been able to sort out the associated function.  I'm guessing I'm just over-complicating things, but help would be appreciated in identifying the appropriate lambda (or method if `reduceByKey` is not most efficient in this scenario).

I've scoured StackOverflow and found similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716047/pyspark-grouby-and-then-get-max-value-of-each-group), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422969/how-to-get-minimum-value-for-each-distinct-key-using-reducebykey-in-scala), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016427/get-the-max-value-for-each-key-in-a-spark-rdd), but again, I've not been able to successfully modify these answers to fit my particular scenario.  Often times, the datetime format seems to trip things up (the datetime format itself is due to the way I parsed the xml, so I can go back and have it parsed as a string if that's helpful).

I've attempted the following, and receive errors for each:

`.reduceByKey(min)` - IndexError: tuple index out of range

`reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x, min(y)))` - IndexError: tuple index out of range (if datetime is converted to string, or error below if in datetime format)

`.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0], min(y)))` - TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable

I expect the final result to be as follows:

```
[('1', datetime.date(2011, 1, 01)),
 ('2', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('3', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01)),
 ('4', datetime.date(2010, 1, 01)),
 ('5', datetime.date(2012, 1, 01))]
```

Comment: try `rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x if x<y else y)`

Comment: @jxc - `IndexError: tuple index out of range` when I try to `.take()`.

Comment: your RDD elements are (id, date) key-value pairs or not?

Comment: @jxc - I understand them to be key, value pairs.  What exactly designates them as such in Spark though? I thought the key was always the first element and the value the 2nd in a 2-element (1-tuple/row) RDD...

Comment: As indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703298/how-to-determine-if-object-is-a-valid-key-value-pair-in-pyspark.  Correct me if I'm misunderstanding though.

Comment: you are right, in a Pair RDD, the first item of the tuple is always the key and 2nd as value. in reduceByKey(lambda x, y:), both x and y are values, so you should not use x[0] or x[1] etc. both x and y are datetime.date objects.

Comment: type is listed as `PipelinedRDD` though for the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  There were several problems.  For starters, here's the applicable syntax.  First off (and after creating a SparkSession of course), I converted the RDD to a dataframe with:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, ['col1', 'col2'])
```

And then carried out a groupBy and aggregation function.  These you'll see on other SO answers, but I thought I'd post this here since it's in the context of my particular scenario.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df= df.groupBy('col1').agg(F.min('col2'))
```

To then return the data to the RDD format, I used

```
result = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[4]))
```

In this particular case, I was also mapped the elements of the 0th and 4th columns of the dataframe back to a tuple assigned to `result`.

In this process, I also discovered some interesting bits that may be helpful to others:

1. I had some Null values in my dataframe that I wasn't aware of
   that continually caused, mostly "NoneType is not subscriptible"
   errors.  While this made sense, it took me a while to figure out
   where the NoneType was located.
2. Some of my XML had been incorrectly parsed so that it was returning a tuple of (None) instead of a tuple of (None, None) as required by the format of data above.

These corrections allowed me to `.show()` the dataframes (and not just `.printSchema()`. The `.groupBy` and its associated objects were never a problem.

Comment: @jxc's answer in the comments may have worked after I resolved the 'None' issue described in this answer, but I didn't get around to trying it out.